# iterate over an array of objects to get sum of quantities that exist

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects.All these objects do not necessarily have the properties in common.

In case some of the objects from an array do have common property, I need to find their sum.

```
[{"taxAmount":572.26,"totalAmount":2004,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":12,"gTotal":2576.2599999999998,"count":4,"deployment":{"_id":"554c92f979d26026307a5a9b","name":"Punjabi Bagh"}},
{"taxAmount":304.9,"totalAmount":1111,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":9,"gTotal":1415.8999999999999,"count":2,"deployment{"_id":"554c930579d26026307a5a9c","name":"Pitampura"}},
{"deployment":{"_id":"554c930c79d26026307a5a9d","name":"Model Town"}},   
{"deployment":{"_id":"554c945079d26026307a5cae","name":"Dwarka"}},
{"deployment":{"_id":"554cd66c0a40ccd2416e38e7","name":"Green Park"}}]
```

In above example, I need to add calculate individual sums of `TaxAmount` and `totalAmount`.

Also, I would need number of objects that have let's say `totalAmount` property.

How can I go about this in javascript?

also, is there a quick way to check if an object has any extra property except for what we have been iterating so far?

Comment: there's a problem with one of your objects here -> `"deployment{"_id":"554`

Comment: To check for a property you can just use `if(Obj.PropertyName)` if it exists add the amount or increment the counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path - reduce is one way to do it (you'll also need `Object.keys` to loop through each object's properties

Comments inline - note that this does a (simple) isNumber check before counting / adding

```
var data = [{"taxAmount":572.26,"totalAmount":2004,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":12,"gTotal":2576.2599999999998,"count":4,"deployment":{"_id":"554c92f979d26026307a5a9b","name":"Punjabi Bagh"}},
{"taxAmount":304.9,"totalAmount":1111,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":9,"gTotal":1415.8999999999999,"count":2,"deployment":{_id:"554c930579d26026307a5a9c","name":"Pitampura"}},
{"deployment":{"_id":"554c930c79d26026307a5a9d","name":"Model Town"}},   
{"deployment":{"_id":"554c945079d26026307a5cae","name":"Dwarka"}},
{ "deployment": { "_id": "554cd66c0a40ccd2416e38e7", "name": "Green Park" } }]

var result = data.reduce(function (a, b) {
    // loop through the properties
    Object.keys(b).forEach(function (key) {
        // check if it's a number
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(b[key]))) {
            // get the running count / sum for this key or initialize a new one
            a[key] = a[key] || { sum: 0, count: 0 }
            a[key].sum += Number(b[key]);
            a[key].count++;
        }
    })

    return a;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was superb. However, There is one thing that's still bothering me.I do not want count of every key.I just want count of objects with a field called totalItems. Calculating it for every key would be such a good idea i guess in that case?

Comment: `data.filter(function (e) { return e.hasOwnProperty('totalItems') }).length` if you just want that. If you want to add that as a constraint in the answer you can just append the filter part before the `reduce` or the `hasOwnProperty` within it around the `forEach`

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = [{"taxAmount":572.26,"totalAmount":2004,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":12,"gTotal":2576.2599999999998,"count":4,"deployment":{"_id":"554c92f979d26026307a5a9b","name":"Punjabi Bagh"}},
{"taxAmount":304.9,"totalAmount":1111,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":9,"gTotal":1415.8999999999999,"count":2,"deployment":{"_id":"554c930579d26026307a5a9c","name":"Pitampura"}},
{"deployment":{"_id":"554c930c79d26026307a5a9d","name":"Model Town"}},   
{"deployment":{"_id":"554c945079d26026307a5cae","name":"Dwarka"}},
{"deployment":{"_id":"554cd66c0a40ccd2416e38e7","name":"Green Park"}}],
    sumObj = { "taxAmount":0, "totalAmount":0 };

for( var o in obj ){
    sumObj.taxAmount += obj[ o ].taxAmount || 0;
    sumObj.totalAmount += obj[ o ].totalAmount || 0;
}
```

This `obj[ o ].taxAmount || 0` tests if `obj[ o ]` has property `taxAmount` and if it's true-like. If it does, return it, else return 0.

Comment: When I said I need to sum taxAmount and totalAMounts, that was for example sake. I do not want to hard code the values that I want to sum. Is there an efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is contained in an array called `values`:

```
var taxAmount = 0,
    totalAmount = 0,
    objectsWithTotalAmount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i].hasOwnProperty("taxAmount") {
        taxAmount += values[i].taxAmount;
    }
    if (values[i].hasOwnProperty("totalAmount") {
        totalAmount += values[i].totalAmount;
        objectsWithTotalAmount++;
    }
}
```

With `.hasOwnProperty()` you check whether the object contains that property. That way you have your sums at `taxAmount` and `totalAmount`, as well as the number of objects that have the `totalAmount` property.

Comment: When I said I need to sum taxAmount and totalAMounts, that was for example sake. I do not want to hard code the values that I want to sum. Is there an efficient way to do that?That is just go about adding the commong properties of objects from array?

Answer (score 1):

Pass in prop name to function, check every property of each array instance

```js
    var testArr = [{"taxAmount":572.26,"totalAmount":2004,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":12,"gTotal":2576.2599999999998,"count":4,"deployment":{"_id":"554c92f979d26026307a5a9b","name":"Punjabi Bagh"}},
    {"taxAmount":304.9,"totalAmount":1111,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":9,"gTotal":1415.8999999999999,"count":2,"deployment":{"_id":"554c930579d26026307a5a9c","name":"Pitampura"}},
    {"deployment":{"_id":"554c930c79d26026307a5a9d","name":"Model Town"}},   
    {"deployment":{"_id":"554c945079d26026307a5cae","name":"Dwarka"}},
    {"deployment":{"_id":"554cd66c0a40ccd2416e38e7","name":"Green Park"}}];
    
    var testTotal = getTotal('taxAmount');
    alert(testTotal);
    
    function getTotal(propName) {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
        for (var key in testArr[i]) {
          if (testArr[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (key === propName) {
              total = total + testArr[i][key];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return total;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you realy want. Is it this ?

```
var obj = [{"taxAmount":572.26,"totalAmount":2004,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":12,"gTotal":2576.2599999999998,"count":4,"deployment":{"_id":"554c92f979d26026307a5a9b","name":"Punjabi Bagh"}},
{"taxAmount":304.9,"totalAmount":1111,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":9,"gTotal":1415.8999999999999,"count":2,"deployment":{"_id":"554c930579d26026307a5a9c","name":"Pitampura"}},
{"deployment":{"_id":"554c930c79d26026307a5a9d","name":"Model Town"}},   
{"deployment":{"_id":"554c945079d26026307a5cae","name":"Dwarka"}},
{"deployment":{"_id":"554cd66c0a40ccd2416e38e7","name":"Green Park"}}],
    sumObj = { "taxAmount":[], "totalAmount":[] };

for( var o in obj ){
    var current = obj[ o ];
    current.taxAmount && sumObj.taxAmount.push( current.taxAmount );
    current.totalAmount && sumObj.totalAmount.push( current.totalAmount  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a recursive function, they're really easy to use in Javascript, just keep passing the same variable:

```
function getSumAllProps(){
   var objSums = {};
   var arrObjs = [{"taxAmount":572.26,"totalAmount":2004,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":12,"gTotal":2576.2599999999998,"count":4,"deployment":{"_id":"554c92f979d26026307a5a9b","name":"Punjabi Bagh"}},{"taxAmount":304.9,"totalAmount":1111,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":9,"gTotal":1415.8999999999999,"count":2,"deployment":{"_id":"554c930579d26026307a5a9c","name":"Pitampura"}},{"deployment":{"_id":"554c930c79d26026307a5a9d","name":"Model Town"}},{"deployment":{"_id":"554c945079d26026307a5cae","name":"Dwarka"}},{"deployment":{"_id":"554cd66c0a40ccd2416e38e7","name":"Green Park"}}];

   for( var prop in arrObjs ){
      sumProps( arrObjs[i], objSums );
   }

   console.log( objSums );
}

function sumProps( objIn, newObjSum ){
   for( var theProp in objIn ){
      if( typeof objIn[ theProp ] === 'object'){
         sumProps( objIn[ theProp ], newObjSum );
      }else{
         if( !newObjSum[ theProp ] ) newObjSum[ theProp ] = 0;
         newObjSum[ theProp ] += objIn[ theProp ];
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [**Array.prototype.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method. Moreover, you can do it by using the **functional way** and **high order function**.

Moreover, you can use the [**Arguments**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object in order to pass multiple parameters.

I've made a **generic** function in order to reduce your data.

```
  var data = [{"taxAmount":572.26,"totalAmount":2004,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":12,"gTotal":2576.2599999999998,"count":4,"deployment":{"_id":"554c92f979d26026307a5a9b","name":"Punjabi Bagh"}},
{"taxAmount":304.9,"totalAmount":1111,"totalDiscount":0,"totalItems":9,"gTotal":1415.8999999999999,"count":2,"deployment":{"_id":"554c930579d26026307a5a9c","name":"Pitampura"}},
{"deployment":{"_id":"554c930c79d26026307a5a9d","name":"Model Town"}},
{"deployment":{"_id":"554c945079d26026307a5cae","name":"Dwarka"}},
{"deployment":{"_id":"554cd66c0a40ccd2416e38e7","name":"Green Park"}}];



function reducer(data, func){
  //Retrieve our arguments parameter
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  //Remove first and second element from array args
  args.splice(0,2);
  //Start reducing our data, initialize with an empty object
  return data.reduce(function(result, current){
    //ForEach key
    args.forEach(function(key){
      //If our object get current key, add curent value, instead of initialize it with 0
      //Apply our high order function
      func(result, current, key);
    });
    //Return our current object result
    return result;
  }, {});
}

//Function to sum some properties
function sum(result, current, key){
  return result[key] = (result[key] || 0) + (current[key] || 0);
}

//Function to count occurence of properties
function number(result, current, key){
  return current.hasOwnProperty(key)
  ? (result[key] = (++result[key] || 1), result)
  : result
}

var res1 = reducer(data, sum, 'taxAmount', 'totalAmount');

var res2 = reducer(data, number, 'taxAmount');
```

So you will be able with one function to sum specific field, or count occurence, just by specifying an high order function.